# Objective C: typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, TestType) with if else condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums, macros

I want to set the enum order according to my phone language in alphabetical order so is this possible to define **typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, TestType)** according to Phone language.

here is my code

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, TestType) {
test1,
test2,
test3,
test4,
test5,
};
```

and i want someting like this

```
#ifdef IsGerman

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, TestType) {
test1,
test2,
test3,
test4,
test5,
};

#else

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, TestType) {
test5,
test2,
test4,
test3,
test5,
};

#endif
```

so please help me with this or any other solution for this

Comment: Why? Why do you want to do that? The phone language shouldn't change that, that's your inner model, the order you want if for IHM, that's not its place. Also, the macro is pre-compilation, so you won't know it when released, exceopt if you have a target for each languages, but that's adding too much issues.

Comment: Probably not - the typedef is set compile time and the language determined run time.